# How to Remove Titles and Suffixes from "Last Name" column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, data-cleaning

Could any one please let me know whether following scenario can be implemented in SQL Server?

Scenario:
Have a "Last Name" column in a table, with values like:

- SMITH **MD**
- GEORGE **MD PHD**
- SMITH **MD LLC**
- SMTITH **JR MD**
- SMITH **III MD PA**
- SMITH**,MD**

In other words, "Last Name" has many titles or suffixes. I want to clean this data using SQL. Currently, I am doing it in multiple views like, first remove only "MD" then in next view "LLC" or "JR" and so on.

Instead, can I dump all these possible suffixes / titles into a table, except last name, and check last name again that table, and if that string is found at the end of "Last Name", then remove it from that column?

Something like:

```
LOCATE(a.LastName, IN (Select Suffix/Title from Code table)) > 0
```

Then remove that whole string again looking at the codes table. Example:

```
Last name is like SMITH MD
```

Codes table will have 2 columns as:

```
Code   Logic
MD     SUBSTRING(a.LastName, 1, length(a.NEWlastname) - 2)
```

to remove that MD for the last name and dump the cleaned data into separate table. So I can use data from that new table for my further processing.

Comment: Trying to perform data cleansing using pure SQL sounds miserable.  SSIS has some capabilities here:  [Clicky!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163731.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you only need the last name.
The last name is always followed by a space. You may use this space to identify the end of last name and avoid anything that follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT YT.USER_NAME,
                SUBSTR(YT.USER_NAME, 0, INSTR(YT.USER_NAME, ' ') - 1) AS ONLY_NAME
  FROM YOUR_TABLE YT
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This solution does not work in all cases. The OP shows a case in his example data (last row that doesn't seem to be formatted correctly) that has no space, just a comma. It also does not allow for Last Names that have a space in them. Also, INSTR is not a SQL Server function.

Answer (score 0):

If using SQLCLR-based functions is an option for you, then you can use a Regular Expression to simply remove one or more matching suffixes. A RegEx "Replace" can match any number of suffixes in a single call (using a pipe "|" to "or" the suffixes) and replace each one with an empty string. Regular Expressions make it easy to match the combination of characters that precede each suffix: space, comma (the two in your example data), as well as a comma and then a space, or even a space plus comma plus space. And this approach allows for last names to have spaces in them. You can populate a table of suffixes (as you requested) but there is no need to store the logic to remove the suffix.

The following example makes use of the [SQL#](https://SQLsharp.com/?ref=so_19947176) library which includes a **RegEx_Replace** function. I'm the author of [SQL#](https://SQLsharp.com/?ref=so_19947176), but this function is in the Free version. Or, if you just want a RegEx "Replace" function without all of the other functions, there are numerous examples on various forums / blogs / articles / etc.

In the following example I included two additional test cases: one with a comma and space (to show that both are removed), and one that is not defined as a suffix (to show that the space before it is not removed).

```
DECLARE @TestNames TABLE (LastName NVARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @TestNames VALUES
        (N'SMITH MD'),
        (N'GEORGE MD PHD'),
        (N'SMITH MD LLC'),
        (N'SMTITH JR MD'),
        (N'SMITH III MD PA'),
        (N'SMITH,MD'),
        (N'SMITH, IV'),
        (N'SMITH NotDefined');

DECLARE @NameSuffixes TABLE (Suffix NVARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @NameSuffixes VALUES
        (N'MD'),
        (N'PHD'),
        (N'llc'),
        (N'II'),
        (N'III'),
        (N'iv'),
        (N'jr'),
        (N'pa');

-- Pattern =
-- (([, ]+MD\b)|([, ]+PHD\b)|([, ]+llc\b)|([, ]+II\b)|([, ]+III\b)|...)
DECLARE @SuffixList NVARCHAR(4000) = N'(';
SELECT @SuffixList += N'([, ]+' + Suffix + N'\b)|'
FROM @NameSuffixes;
SET @SuffixList += N')';

SELECT tn.LastName, 
    SQL#.RegEx_Replace(tn.LastName, @SuffixList, '', -1, 1, N'IgnoreCase') + N'~'
FROM @TestNames tn;
```

Please note that the `~` appended to each filtered value is just to show that there are no trailing spaces.